# Unable to mount a shared folder on VirtualBox?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, shared-folders

I've set up an VirtualBox with CentOS 7 but i can not add a shared folder.

Enviroment:

```
Host - Windows 10
VirtBox - Centos 7 
VirtBox Version - 5.1.10
Development Tools are installed
gcc version - gcc-Version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC)
perl version - v5.16.3
```

I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328775/virtualbox-mount-vboxsf-mounting-failed-with-the-error-no-such-device) but it does not work.

If I try to mount I get the following result

`[root@localhost /]# mount -t vboxsf php5 /mnt/share/php5/
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device`

If I run `sudo ./vboxadd setup` , descripted in the post, the log-file get the following message:

```
[root@localhost /]# cat /var/log/vboxadd-install.log
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Schluss.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Here is an image of the added folder
[image]

If I try it by the common was `Device`--> `Guest Addition` the following error occure:

[image]

Is there an other way to the success??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most guest addition related problems in virtualbox is solved by creating a group at the host named vboxusers (if not created already)

```
groupadd vboxusers
```

and add your user to that group:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers $your_username
```

Comment: I try it out, but it does not work.  If i run `[root@localhost ~]# mount -t vboxsf php5 /mnt/share/ ` i get the error `/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device`

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328775/virtualbox-mount-vboxsf-mounting-failed-with-the-error-no-such-device `cd /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*/init`  
`sudo ./vboxadd setup`

Comment: yes, I did. In case of this i get this message `sudo ./vboxadd setup
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Please check that you have gcc, make, the header files for your Linux kernel and possibly perl installed..
`

Comment: In Vbox guest additions image, there is a run file, did you execute that script to install Vbox additions? Do you have the dependencies in strerr (gcc, make, etc) at the guest? And did you try these as a non-root user?

Comment: yes I run this file in the image,  gcc, make, and the others in the "developer tools" are up to date ( nothing to do ). I've work a a root user.

Comment: i run this command again  `[root@localhost cdrom]# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` but i get same error in the log file.  `vboxadd.sh: failed: Please check that you have gcc, make, the header files for your Linux kernel and possibly perl installed..`

Comment: Could you please run the vboxadd.sh with -x option (you can edit the shebang line in the script as such: #!/bin/bash -x, in order to debug and see where the problem is?

Comment: ok, i added `-x` to the file,  this is the current output of the command : `[root@localhost init]# sh vboxadd setup
which: no vboxadd in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin)
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.
vboxadd.sh: You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used.
vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
`

Comment: now i use  `yum install dkms` ... now the shared folder is mounted!

Comment: OK, guest can't find vboxadd. Could you please see whether there is any vboxadd in the file system by `sudo find / -name "vboxadd*"`. If there is one, check whether it is executable (ls -l reports "x" permissions), if not, do so by `chmod +x /path/to/vboxadd`.  And then you can create a symlink to that executable by sudo `ln -s /path/to/vboxadd /usr/binvboxadd`

Comment: Ok great, I am happy that you solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [small tutorial](http://it-mammut.blogspot.co.at/search/label/Oracle%20VirtualBox%20Shared-Folder?view=classic) to fix it.